# How to install SSL certificate (and enable HTTPS) on VPS via command line?

Tags: apache, https, vps

I am having a bit of an issue. I have purchased an SSL certificate from GoDaddy and have it and the private key uploaded on my server.

I have followed [this](https://support.servergrove.com/how-do-i-install-ssl-certificate-in-a-vps/) guide but nothing is working for me.

My website loads without styling when trying to access it on HTTPS.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You mention your website loads without styling when trying to access it via https. If the certificate is installed properly and you are able to view the https version of your site without any browser/ssl validation errors your issue might be that the source of your website might be trying to load the css files (or any other files) from the non secure http version of your site which your browser might be blocking since it is technically insecure http content being requested from a https secure site. Are you using absolute paths or relative paths to load content on your site?

Answer (score 1):

If your website is appearing with HTTPS. then I believe you've correctly installed the SSL certificate. Since CSS is not loading, make sure that CSS/JS files are also loaded with https. To load CSS/JS correctly, do not use absolute URLs, use relative URLs instead.